# Why are Django signals removed without weak=False?

Tags: python, django

**UPDATE**
The code posted below is perfectly fine. I just found the answer to my question: I was overwriting the handler with another one that used the same name on that module, so the weakref was being deleted... Others can use the code below to properly register signals according to the Django documentation.

In my Django 1.8, Python 2.7.9 I define a signal that never gets called. It looks like for some reason it is being garbage collected. The handler is defined at the module level, not inside a function so I expected it to stay there as long as the program is running. Using weak=False when connecting the signal solves the issue, but I'd like to know the specifics of this behaviour.

This is roughly the code I'm using:

```
#  myapp/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):

    name = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        import myapp.signals
```

```
#  myapp/__init__.py

default_app_config = 'myapp.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

```
#  myapp/signals.py

from django.db.models.signals import post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from otherapp.models import Model

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Model)  # weak=True
def post_delete_hype_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    # Do stuff here
    pass
```

The post_delete signal on Model never gets called. I can't even see it in the list of connected signals. Using weak=False on the receiver decorator solves the issue.

From my point of view, the receiver decorator returns the actual function being decorated, so it should stay at the module level and never be garbage collected. I've also checked that the handler gets connected to the signal when the app calls ready (by the use of `import myapp.signals`).

The only reasonable explanation I can think of is that once the `ready()` method of MyAppConfig finishes the `signals.py` module gets garbage collected as there are no other references to it anywhere, but this is not the behaviour I expected.

This seems to be the recommended way of connecting signals according to the Django documentation, but doesn't seem to be working for me.

Can anyone shed some light on this behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just found the answer to my question: the code was perfectly fine, but I was overwriting the function with a different handler that I defined below it with the same name... -.-u That is why that handler was being garbage collected when weakrefs where being used. I'll leave the question here so others can see how to properly connect signals according to the Django documentation.